# Places autosuggestions in android not working even after enabling Places API

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am making an activity using Google Places API for my app in which the search bar auto suggests the places.
I am getting an error:-

> "Error contacting
>   API:status{statusCode:PLACES_API_ACCESS_NOT_CONFIGURED,resolution=null}"

Here is my code for the **activity**:-

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Map is Ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onMapReady: map is ready");
        mMap = googleMap;

        if (mLocationPermissionsGranted) {
            getDeviceLocation();

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);

            init();
        }
    }

    private static final String TAG = "MapActivity";

    private static final String FINE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
    private static final String COURSE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;
    private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;
    private static final float DEFAULT_ZOOM = 15f;
    private static final LatLngBounds LAT_LNG_BOUNDS = new LatLngBounds(
            new LatLng(-40, -168), new LatLng(71, 136));


    //widgets
    private AutoCompleteTextView mSearchText;
    private ImageView mGps;

    //vars
    private Boolean mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;
    public PlaceAutoCompleteAdapter mPlaceAutocompleteAdapter;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        mSearchText = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.input_search);
        mGps = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ic_gps);

        getLocationPermission();

    }

    private void init(){
        Log.d(TAG, "init: initializing");

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
                .Builder(this)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                .enableAutoManage(MapActivity.this,  this)
                .build();

        mPlaceAutocompleteAdapter = new PlaceAutoCompleteAdapter(this, mGoogleApiClient,
                LAT_LNG_BOUNDS, null);

        mSearchText.setAdapter(mPlaceAutocompleteAdapter);

        mSearchText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int actionId, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH
                        || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE
                        || keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                        || keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){

                    //execute our method for searching
                    geoLocate();
                }

                return false;
            }
        });

        mGps.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: clicked gps icon");
                getDeviceLocation();
            }
        });

        hideSoftKeyboard();
    }

    private void geoLocate(){
        Log.d(TAG, "geoLocate: geolocating");

        String searchString = mSearchText.getText().toString();

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MapActivity.this);
        List<Address> list = new ArrayList<>();
        try{
            list = geocoder.getFromLocationName(searchString, 1);
        }catch (IOException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "geoLocate: IOException: " + e.getMessage() );
        }

        if(list.size() > 0){
            Address address = list.get(0);

            Log.d(TAG, "geoLocate: found a location: " + address.toString());
            //Toast.makeText(this, address.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            moveCamera(new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude()), DEFAULT_ZOOM,
                    address.getAddressLine(0));
        }
    }

    private void getDeviceLocation(){
        Log.d(TAG, "getDeviceLocation: getting the devices current location");

        mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        try{
            if(mLocationPermissionsGranted){

                final Task location = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
                location.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: found location!");
                            Location currentLocation = (Location) task.getResult();

                            moveCamera(new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude()),
                                    DEFAULT_ZOOM,
                                    "My Location");

                        }else{
                            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: current location is null");
                            Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, "unable to get current location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }catch (SecurityException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "getDeviceLocation: SecurityException: " + e.getMessage() );
        }
    }

    private void moveCamera(LatLng latLng, float zoom, String title){
        Log.d(TAG, "moveCamera: moving the camera to: lat: " + latLng.latitude + ", lng: " + latLng.longitude );
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom));

        if(!title.equals("My Location")){
            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(latLng)
                    .title(title);
            mMap.addMarker(options);
        }

        hideSoftKeyboard();
    }

    private void initMap(){
        Log.d(TAG, "initMap: initializing map");
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(MapActivity.this);
    }

    private void getLocationPermission(){
        Log.d(TAG, "getLocationPermission: getting location permissions");
        String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                    COURSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                mLocationPermissionsGranted = true;
                initMap();
            }else{
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        permissions,
                        LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        }else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    permissions,
                    LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: called.");
        mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;

        switch(requestCode){
            case LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:{
                if(grantResults.length > 0){
                    for(int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++){
                        if(grantResults[i] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                            mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;
                            Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: permission failed");
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: permission granted");
                    mLocationPermissionsGranted = true;
                    //initialize our map
                    initMap();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void hideSoftKeyboard(){
        this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
}
```

And here is my manifest file in which my key is configured:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyDWJJhx9DvZlYbHNT22YTsgV2DGWOQi2Ak"/>


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MapActivity"></activity>

    <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
</application>
```

I have also seen my developer console and the **Places API** is enabled.

It is still not working. It is showing error. 
Please anyone can tell me what am I doing wrong here? Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Follow below guideline..

first enable PlacesAPI in developer console, then install Client Library by updating in gradle.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55045772/10579969

Answer (score 2):

The Google Play Services version of the Places SDK for Android (in Google Play Services 16.0.0) is deprecated as of January 29, 2019, and will be turned off on July 29, 2019. You can migrate to the New Places SDK Client using this [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration)

Comment: I have made this app yesterday so I guess I have new Places SDK. Can you suggest any other option for solving that

Comment: Writing this app yesterday doesn't necessarily mean everything is up to date. Make sure to add `implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:1.0.0'` and remove `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'` from your app level build.gradle file

Answer (score 1):

please try to add this `import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.Places;`

check here for details: [AutoComplete Migration Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54965020/apiexception-9003-places-api-access-not-configured/54969500#54969500)

Hope it'll work

Comment: Hi Rica, I am not able to add this import in my activity. Can you please share the code.
I have added this import and it was showing error in the activity

Comment: add this dependency in your build.gradle `implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:1.0.0'`