# AutocompleteSupportFragment.setPlaceFields crushes App on start

Tags: java, android

First,i'd like to say that i'm new in this "Programming world", but I've been struggling with autocompleteFragment by google Places,
i'm trying to implement autocompleteFragment in my app, but after entering in my "Welcome Activity" it throws an error and crushes the App:

```
    Process: com.app.mk.transport, PID: 20295
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.mk.transport/com.app.mk.transport.Welcome}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment.setPlaceFields(java.util.List)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment.setPlaceFields(java.util.List)' on a null object reference
        at com.app.mk.transport.Welcome.setUpLocationPicker(Welcome.java:237)
        at com.app.mk.transport.Welcome.onCreate(Welcome.java:216)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

And this is my code:

```
        if (!Places.isInitialized()) {
            Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(R.string.google_api_key));
        }
            autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ADDRESS));


        autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {

                if (location_switch.isChecked()) {
                    destination = place.getAddress();
                    destination = destination.replace(" ", "+");
                    getDirection();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Status status) {
                // TODO: Handle the error.
                Toast.makeText(Welcome.this, "" + status.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.i(TAG, "An error occurred: " + status);
            }
        });
```

i'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but if someone could point out what's my mistake i would really appreciate it.

And if i need to show you something else "code" or anything just tell me if i'm missing it out!

Thank you.

Comment: Have you found the solution? I am facing the same error

Comment: @AbhayBohra See My answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi this issues comes when implementing in fragment .Use **getChildFragmentManager**  instead of  **getSupportFragmentManager/getFragmentManger()**. 
This will work perfectly.Like this:-

```
if (!Places.isInitialized()) {
        Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "YOUR_API_KEY");
    }


// Initialize the AutocompleteSupportFragment.

AutocompleteSupportFragment autocompleteFragment = (AutocompleteSupportFragment)
        getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);


autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME));


autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
        // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
        Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName() + ", " + place.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Status status) {
        // TODO: Handle the error.
        Log.i(TAG, "An error occurred: " + status);
    }
});
```

This worked for me hope this will also worked for you. Thanks....

Comment: I have try adding this already but Its not working. I am using this in activity itself.

Comment: @AbhayBohra .Will you using this on Activity or fregment?

Comment: I am using it in activity

Comment: @AbhayBohra Check you code at once and do step by step as i have write steps in this link :-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54965020/apiexception-9003-places-api-access-not-configured/54969500#54969500

Comment: then it will worked perfectly.  Check you code and do follows steps from migration guide:-https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration

Answer (score 0):

If you are using into activity then Use `<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView>` instead `< <fragment>` tag.

And for add  implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.0" dependency.